# Couldn't manipulate labels and fields bootstrap

Tags: html, css, label, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap template,
I couldn't manipulate the size of the labels and the fields input also their dispostion (align left) , the two images below display what I want and what I have.
 I seen the documentation (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid ) about the grid system but I couldnt understand it.

**what I have:**

[image]

**what I want**
[image]

the code used:

```
<div class="container fluid custom-locale-form">
 <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="numeroTelephone" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-control-label">Information</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">

        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="numeroTelephone" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-control-label">Numéro de téléphone</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            {{ form_widget(form.numeroTelephone, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="numeroFax" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-control-label">Numéro de fax</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            {{ form_widget(form.numeroFax, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-control-label">E-mail</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-control-label">Site web</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
            {{ form_widget(form.siteWeb, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you citing Bootstrap 3 docs while having a `bootstrap-4` tag for this question? Those two versions are incompatible with each other. Choose one.

Comment: it's Bootstrap v3.3.7  I couldnt find a bootstrap3 as a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments on your code.

1. When using the grid layout, it's enough to set the smaller resolution class so it will also fit bigger screens. So instead of having `col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3` you can just have the smaller one and delete all the other classes: `class="col-xs-3"`
2. You can set the offset of a column to add some spacing before or after, like: `class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1"`. This way, you will remain inside the '3 columns' width, but having the first column as blank space, having the content width limited to 2 columns. That would be my aim for starters. If you need a fixed indentation (not using columns) for labels, then simply add paddings to the labels with a specific CSS rule. Something like:

   ```
   .form-group label {
     padding-left: 20px;
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you, I have solved it using   class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1 , I didn't know about the role of the  offset